# Is TinyMCE free to use?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm not sure I understand it correctly, but I believe that there is a "basic" version that is free of charge, you only have to pay if you want some premium plugins and technical support.

Is this how the situation truly is?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**yes**.

Please see [this link](http://archive.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=556) and [this link](https://community.tinymce.com/communityQuestion?id=90661000000If4NAAS) for more information.

> Anyone that wants to use TinyMCE in their commercial application or website are free to do so.

On top of this,the code is licensed under [LGPL](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x//extras/TinyMCE3x@License/), so you may fork the code. Just remember to contribute your changes where other people can see it.(fork on github for example)

If you want support or want to contribute to the development, you are welcome to buy support or get [addition plugins with the enterprise version](https://www.tinymce.com/pricing/#demo-enterprise). But only if you want.

[Related](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47323/can-i-use-an-lgpl-licenced-library-in-my-commercial-app).

EDIT:
If you use a tool like Webpack, remember that the TinyMCE files should not be bundled and minified with the rest of your application. It should be a seperate Java Script and resource files. TinyMCE even has it's own CDN to help you with this.

"It should also be possible to exchange that dynamically linked library for an independently compiled build"

Comment: I am confused. as I want to use it in an enterprise application and found this link. Not sure if its really free now?
https://community.tiny.cloud/communityQuestion?id=9066100000096nGAAQ

Comment: from the first link " LGPL software is focused on libraries. And anything that uses LGPL libraries may or may not be commercial as long as the license of the library is not changed and the whole application with source is distributed with the product." So, the way I understand it, as long as you don't change the library, it's free

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation. I got it.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation.  I think TinyMCE and CKEdit go out of their way to make it ambiguous as to whether they are free/open source or not.  Maybe that's their business plan.  Or maybe I'm just not good at reading licenses.

Answer (score 1):

I am installing it from this address by typing "npm install tinymce" as of 2021-01-03, according to the information I received from the site, it is open source and free.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tinymce

> TinyMCE is the world’s most popular open source web-based WYSIWYG editor.
>
> Trusted and loved by millions of developers, and integrated into thousands of applications, such as:
>
> Content management systems (CMSs)
> Learning management systems (LMSs)
> Customer relationship management (CRM) and marketing automation systems
> Email marketing systems
> Content creation in SaaS systems

The confusing "https://www.tiny.cloud/pricing" written on the tinymce page but according to the paragraph COMMUNITY it is free forever.

> Free Forever
> The open source editor you know and love, free forever and ready for commercial use.

Comment: There are some plugins labeled as premium and are not free now.

Comment: The features in core are free. : https://www.tiny.cloud/tinymce/features/

Fee information : https://www.tiny.cloud/pricing/


The table feature, which was free before, seems to have been paid. It appears under "Premium features".

https://www.tiny.cloud/tinymce/features/advanced-tables/#advanced-tables-demo

Answer (score -2):

use this bellow init to have menu bar and toolbar for free without any problem

```
 tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  min_height: 350,
   skin: "oxide",
   icons: 'material' ,
 preview_styles: 'font-size color',
  resize: 'both',
  plugins: 'link image media code autolink lists media table',
  toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect| forecolor  | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent | link image media| code table',
  toolbar_mode: 'floating',
   /* enable title field in the Image dialog*/
  image_title: true,
  /* enable automatic uploads of images represented by blob or data URIs*/automatic_uploads: true,images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php',file_picker_types: 'image',

  tinycomments_mode: 'embedded',
  tinycomments_author: 'Author name'
  
});
```